# MIME parser test data

Tags: unit-testing, mime, mime-message

I've just wrote MIME parser and tested it on 1000+ messages from my inbox, so looks like it's working well. However, most of these messages are private and I cannot use them in public unit tests or add them to VCS.

Are there any well-known/public sets of mail messages to be used for MIME parser unit testing?

I thought about extracting original MIME messages from public mailing lists by HTTP, but it will make test very slow and non-repeatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.imc.org/mimetest/ is a repository for one such set of testing messages.  Like the page details, such sets have been the targets for spammers in the past, so it could be one reason they're a bit hard to find.

Comment: But here's something for testing MIME validity one message at a time ... http://www.mimevalidator.net/

Comment: Although "Due to its abuse by spammers, the tool is no longer available" [(1)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121062742/http://www.imc.org:80/mimetest/), the Wayback Machine captured the [source messages](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.imc.org/mimetest/MimeBack.tgz) (tgz) that imc.org had released before removing the service altogether.